# Is my PEAR package installation okay?

Tags: php, pear

I want to install PEAR's Mail package. I went through the Terminal and installed Mail and its dependencies. The files were saved to my /usr/lib/php directory. In that lib directory I also have a 'PEAR' directory but my new packages weren't saved there. Do I need to drop the new packages into the PEAR directory or is it okay to let them sit in the usr/lib/php dir where they were installed?

Answer (score 1):

You should install the package the official way via the installer:

```
pear install mail
```

It takes care of putting the files in the right directories.